# Error to render compiling AST AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute

Tags: xml, odoo

I get the following error when I try to modify a rapport of an invoice module. I use *odoo 11* and this is the error:

```
File "/home/omar/odoo/odoo11/odoo/addons/base/ir/ir_qweb/qweb.py", line 272, in render
    self.compile(template, options)(self, body.append, values or {})
  File "/home/omar/odoo/odoo11/odoo/addons/base/ir/ir_qweb/qweb.py", line 345, in _compiled_fn
    raise e
  File "/home/omar/odoo/odoo11/odoo/addons/base/ir/ir_qweb/qweb.py", line 343, in _compiled_fn
    return compiled(self, append, new, options, log)
  File "<template>", line 1, in template_562_2862
  File "<template>", line 2, in body_call_content_2861
  File "<template>", line 3, in foreach_2860
  File "/home/omar/odoo/odoo11/odoo/addons/base/ir/ir_qweb/qweb.py", line 350, in _compiled_fn
    raise QWebException("Error to render compiling AST", e, path, node and etree.tostring(node[0], encoding='unicode'), name)
odoo.addons.base.ir.ir_qweb.qweb.QWebException: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'caseacocher'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/omar/odoo/odoo11/odoo/addons/base/ir/ir_qweb/qweb.py", line 343, in _compiled_fn
    return compiled(self, append, new, options, log)
  File "<template>", line 1, in template_account_report_invoice_document_with_payments_2933
  File "<template>", line 2, in body_call_content_2932
  File "<template>", line 82, in foreach_2896
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'caseacocher'

Error to render compiling AST
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'caseacocher'
Template: account.report_invoice_document_with_payments
```

Comment: Please, show the xml code ?

Comment: The error log shows `doc.caseacocher` and the xml code uses `l.caseacocher_account_invoice`.Please update your module and check again.

Comment: I incorporated the XML from the comment section and added a final closing tag.